# How do we save and retrieve a variable in a struct across multiple calls?

Tags: rust

We are trying to save a sentence in a struct and need to initialize it beforehand or the struct will not be known inside of the match statement (see code further down `let data = ...`).

When we call the function twice (as seen in the `fn main` part) it overwrites the previously saved sentence with the default initialized struct and returns that instead.

Is there some way to keep that sentence saved and known within the match statement for "RET" without using a unsafe global variable?

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Test {
    satz: String,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn testing(message: &str) -> Result<Option<String>, &'static str> {
        let mut vs: Vec<&str> = message.split(' ').collect();
        let mut i = 0;  
        while vs[i] != "\n" {
            i += 1;
            if i > vs.len() {
                Err("wrong format.").unwrap()
            }
        }
        vs.truncate(i);
        let data: Test = Default::default();
        match vs[0] {
            "PUB" => {
                let data = Test { satz: vs.join(" ") };
                Ok(None)
            }
            "RET" => {
                let x = data.satz;
                Ok(Some(x))
            }
            _ => Err("wrong format.")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    Test::testing("PUBLISH Hey this is a short message! \n");
    let a = Test::testing("RETRIEVE \n").unwrap().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Comment: As you seem to speak German, now I'm curious: is this a university or school assignment? If so, what university/school? ^_^

Comment: But regarding your question: I unfortunately fail to understand what your program is supposed to do. Right now it panics, because you mix `PUB` and `PUBLISH`. But from your description it seems that this is not the problem you are talking about, so please fix the panic so that we can concentrate on the main problem. But again: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to have a getter/setter in one method? Please modify your question to clarify these things, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> the previously saved sentence

You seem to be very confused about how and where data is stored. I **strongly encourage** you to re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book). In this specific case, you should take extra care to re-read up to and including [methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/method-syntax.html).

Plainly said, there's nowhere for `Test::testing` to store data. Methods that access per-instance data have a `self` argument. `Test::testing` is an *associated function*, not a method.

Adding `&mut self` to the function makes it a method, then replace all uses of `data` with `self`:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Test {
    satz: String,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn testing(&mut self, message: &str) -> Result<Option<String>, &'static str> {
        let mut vs: Vec<_> = message.split(' ').collect();
        let mut i = 0;  
        while vs[i] != "\n" {
            i += 1;
            if i > vs.len() {
                Err("wrong format.").unwrap()
            }
        }
        vs.truncate(i);

        match vs[0] {
            "PUB" => {
                self.satz = vs.join(" ");
                Ok(None)
            }
            "RET" => {
                Ok(Some(self.satz.clone()))
            }
            _ => Err("wrong format.")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Test::default();
    t.testing("PUB Hey this is a short message! \n").unwrap();
    let a = t.testing("RET \n").unwrap().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Note that the compiler attempted to tell you that something was wrong:

```
warning: unused variable: `data`
```

It appears that you think that `data` has some special meaning that would allow it to persist across function calls — there is no such thing. Persisting across functions, without being explicit where the data is stored, *would* be a global variable, and those are undesirable for many reasons.

Additionally, you *should not ignore warnings*, like

```
warning: unused result which must be used
```

If something can't fail, call `expect` (or if you must, `unwrap`).

---

FWIW, I'd write it like

```
impl Test {
    pub fn testing(&mut self, message: &str) -> Result<Option<String>, &'static str> {
        let message = message.trim();
        let mut parts = message.splitn(2, " ");

        match parts.next() {
            Some("PUB") => {
                let msg = parts.next().ok_or("wrong format.")?;
                self.satz = msg.to_owned();
                Ok(None)
            }
            Some("RET") => {
                Ok(Some(self.satz.clone()))
            }
            _ => Err("wrong format.")
        }
    }
}
```